# Given $3$ positive integers $a,b,c$ such that $a>b>c$ how to prove it's always $a^2 - b^2 > b^2-c^2$

Tags: integers

I'm new to this site. Apparently It looks like that given $3$ positive integers $a,b,c$  such that  $a>b>c$ it's always true that $$a^2 - b^2 > b^2-c^2$$

I'm having a hard time proving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are they in arithmetic progression or something?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo a,b,c can be any positive integers with the only condition a>b>c

Comment: please be careful when asking questions, be considerate of the answerers!

Comment: Since you're new to this site:[How to ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $a>c$
we get $$a^2>ac>c^2$$
and $$-a^2<-c^2$$
Finally adding $b^2$.....

Or you could note that $$b^2-a^2<0<b^2-c^2$$

Comment: Thanks you for the answer.. I have typed the question wrong.. Just edited it

Comment: But your new inequality is false..Try $a=10,b=9,c=1$

Comment: Yeah, Go it.. my initial problem was to find a contradiction in equations  series like p^2 + k = q^2, q^2 + k  = t^2, t^2 + k = n^2 ....... where p,q,t, ... are positive integers and k is a positive integer constant to show that there can't be such k and I ended up asking above question. Can you give me any clue or should I ask a new question?

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty obvious. The left side is negative because b < a and the right side is positive because b > c.

Unless you didn't mean that.

EDIT to answer the edited question:

THAT is not true. 
Take 1, 3, 4. 16-9=7 while 9-1=8.

Comment: Yeah :) ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: mistake I have to edit the question

Comment: I edited the answer

Comment: Thank you. my initial problem was to find a contradiction in equations series like p^2 + k = q^2, q^2 + k = t^2, t^2 + k = n^2 ....... where p,q,t, ... are positive integers and k is a positive integer constant to show that there can't be such k and I ended up asking above question. Can you give me any clue or should I ask a new question?

Answer (score 1):

Under the new interpretation it is false.

Let $a=5,b=4,c=1$. Then $a^2-b^2=9$ and $b^2-c^2=15$.

Comment: Got it, Thanks.. Yeah, Go it.. my initial problem was to find a contradiction in equations series like p^2 + k = q^2, q^2 + k = t^2, t^2 + k = n^2 ....... where p,q,t, ... are positive integers and k is a positive integer constant to show that there can't be such k and I ended up asking above question. Can you give me any clue or should I ask a new question?

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are asking about is false.

Take integers $r > s > 0$ with additional inequality 
$$   r > s \left( 1 + \sqrt 2 \right). $$
Then take
$$ a = r^2 + 2rs - s^2, \; \; b = r^2 + s^2, \; \; c = r^2 - 2 r s - s^2. $$
The result is
$$ a > b > c > 0, $$
$$ a^2 - b^2 = b^2 - c^2. $$
It is also true that
$$ a-1 > b > c > 0, $$
$$ (a-1)^2 - b^2 < b^2 - c^2. $$

Comment: Yeah, Go it.. my initial problem was to find a contradiction in equations series like p^2 + k = q^2, q^2 + k = t^2, t^2 + k = n^2 ....... where p,q,t, ... are positive integers and k is a positive integer constant to show that there can't be such k and I ended up asking above question. Can you give me any clue or should I ask a new question?

Comment: @MahelaGunawardana ask a new question